# How do I prevent inserted images from clustering?

Tags: excel, vba

I have **two sheets and one userform.**
Sheet2 starts off completely empty. Sheet1 is completely empty except for one ActiveX command button that opens the userform when clicked.
The userform has one single label, that when clicked, will run some vba code that (1) inserts an image at a specified location in Sheet2 and then (2) inserts a row in Sheet2 above the image

My **goal** is to click on the userform's label *X* number of times such that I will end up with *X* number of images in sheet2 each separated one row apart from each other (my actual use case involves different images).

The **problem** I am facing is that when I first open the excel file (with sheet1 as the default sheet that appears upon opening) and start using my ActiveX command button as described, then when I navigate over to sheet2 to take a look, the images in sheet2 are all clustered together on top of each other.

Strangely enough, after I navigate over to sheet2 to take a look, then navigate back to sheet1 to continue using the ActiveX command button, then navigate back to sheet2 again to take another look, the subsequent images are now all neatly spaced out as intended.

**Is there a way to make sure that right from the start, the images don't cluster when I first open my excel file and use the ActiveX command button?**

Code contained in sheet1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Code contained in the userform (substitute your own pic filepath)

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    Dim pic
    Set pic = Sheet2.Shapes.AddPicture(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\" _
    & "Pictures\Account Pictures\monkey selfie.jpg", _
    False, True, 1, 1, -1, -1)
        pic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        pic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    If pic.Height / pic.Width <= 14.3 / 47 Then
        pic.Width = 40
    ElseIf pic.Height / pic.Width > 14.3 / 47 Then
        pic.Height = 10
    End If
    With pic
        .Top = 20
        .Left = 20
    End With 'this position corresponds to cell A2
    Sheet2.Range("A2") = "Filled" 'to indicate that the cell _
    is supposed to contain an image
    Sheet2.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown 'both the image and _
    the word "Filled" should be pushed down one row
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason not to add the next image below any existing image?  FYI if you want to position an image over a cell then (eg) `pic.Top = Sheet2.Range("A2").Top` would be more robust.

Comment: Yep, my reason is that I need the most recent images to be at the top of the sheet. Thanks for the tip :). I will use it but it still doesn't seem to solve the problem in this case